# What class(es) should I use for basic bitmap operations in GAE?

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine, bitmap

I have to get some code running on the GAE and it does some very basic bitmap manipulation. What I fundamentally need to do is:

1. Convert a bitmap from one format to another (usually to PNG).
2. Get the metadata of an image: size in pixels, DPI, & bitmap format.
3. Resize an image.
4. Walk the pixels in a bitmap to read and/or set them (this can be slow - rarely used).

Also, it would be terrific if there's a class that will convert metafiles to a bitmap?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

For basic image manipulation (resize, crop, rotate etc.), you can use the [Images API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/) and in particular, the interface [`com.google.appengine.api.images.Image`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/Image).

The API seems to support many of the requirements that you mention.

Comment: That has some, but I don't think all. I don't see any way to get the DPI of a bitmap or to read/write the pixels in a bitmap. Am I missing something? thanks - dave

Comment: No, you are right. You could use `ImageIO` if it was whitelisted. You can star the issue in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1268). Here is [another SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018431/how-does-google-app-engine-manipulate-image-data-how-can-you-manipulate-pixel-d) regarding pixel manipulation. If you are feeling up for it, you could also dive into Python on App Engine where you can use the Python Image library (PIL).

Comment: Not the answer I needed. This is nuts that their Image support is so minimal. Anyways, thank you.